# Problem rounding numbers in C++ with a BMI calculator

Tags: c++

I', trying to make a simple BMI calculator using C++. When I input my personal height and weight, I get the correct result but I can't round the number to the nearest whole number. I looked up some videos and some articles and many of them suggested using the "round()" function. I tried that and the result I got was 0!
All feedback helps. Thanks!

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>

using namespace std;

float Calculate(float kilo, float centimeter)
{
    float meter = centimeter * 100;
    return kilo / (meter * meter);
}


int main()
{
    float kilo, centimeter;
    float bmi;

    cout << "BMI calculator." << endl;
    cout << "Please enter your weight in kilograms. ";
    cin >> kilo;
    cout <<"Please enter your height in centimeters. ";
    cin >> centimeter;

    bmi = Calculate(kilo, centimeter);

    cout << round(bmi) << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What inputs did you use?

Comment: I have a feeling your formula is wrong and unless you're a millimeter high you'll get zero. Hint: Meters to centimeters is x 100, but the reverse is / 100, as in a meter is 100 *centi*meters.

Comment: as @tadman says you want `float meter = centimeter / 100;` but what an idea to ask for the size in centimeter while reading a float number, I prefer to enter `1.68` rather than `168`

Answer (score 5):

Your formula for calculating BMI is wrong just change the line `float meter = centimeter/100;`.
because according to your formula any number multiplied by 100 and then squared becomes so big that you get very small floating point number after the division with weight that is eventually rounded that's why you always get `0` in output.